# How can I find out what RAM is in my ProLiant DL380p?

Tags: memory, hp, hp-proliant

I know what RAM is compatible with my server, but without taking the lid off I don't know what specific modules I've got.

It took two seconds to find out from vSphere that I've got eight(8) 8GB DDR3 1333MHz modules in the thing, but I don't know if they're registered or unbuffered, Single Rank or Dual Rank, low voltage or not, or what their timings are.

What's the quickest and most painless way to find out this information so I can buy some more RAM and know 100% that it will work?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please look at your server's [ILO4 interface](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/products/servers/ilo/).

It will detail each RAM module, its slot number, HP Part Number, capacity, frequency, load (rank) and heath status.

[image]

Comment: Marked as answer because iLO proved to be the best method. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to "know 100% that it will work", you should not only look at the modules already installed but also at which module configurations are listed as supported in your [Proliant's QuickSpecs](http://www8.hp.com/h20195/v2/GetDocument.aspx?docname=c04128241) (I assume this is a DL380p G8), the User Guide or the [HP Memory Configurator](http://www.hp.com/go/ddr3memory-configurator).

An excerpt from the relevant QuickSpecs' section:

---

[image]

General Memory Population Rules and Guidelines:

- White DIMM slots denote the first slot of a channel. For 1 DPC (DIMM per channel) populate white slots only.
- A minimum of one DIMM is required per server.
- Install DIMMs only if the corresponding processor is installed.
- If only one processor is installed in a two processor system, only half of the DIMM slots are available.
- To maximize performance, it is recommended to balance the total memory capacity between all installed processors and
  to load the channels similarly whenever possible.
- When two processors are installed, balance the DIMMs across the two processors.
- Populate DIMMs from heaviest load (quad-rank) to lightest load (single-rank) within a channel. Heaviest load (DIMM with
  most ranks) within a channel goes furthest from the processor.
- RDIMMs operating at either 1.35V or 1.5V may be mixed in any order, but the system will power them at the higher
  voltage.
- Do not mix RDIMMs, LRDIMMs, and UDIMMs.
- LRDIMMs are supported up to 3 DIMMs per channel.
- Using the HP RBSU, 1.35V DIMMs can be changed to operate at 1.5V.
- DIMMs of different speeds may be mixed in any order; the server will select a common optimal speed.
- The maximum memory speed is a function of the memory type, memory configuration, and processor model.
- The maximum memory capacity is a function of the memory type and number of installed processors.
- HP memory from previous generation servers is not qualified on the DL380p Gen8 Server. Certain HP SmartMemory
  features such as memory authentication and enhanced performance may not be supported.
- To realize the performance memory capabilities listed in this document, HP SmartMemory is required. For additional
  information, please see the HP SmartMemory QuickSpecs at:
  http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/14225_na/14225_na.html

---

You indeed would need a bit of information about the current configuration. You *might* get it by going through the output of `dmidecode`, the *supported* route though would be running HP Insight Diagnostics from the Intelligent Provisioning suite accessible by hitting F10 during BIOS POST. See the [Intelligent Provisioning docs](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/public/psi/home/?sp4ts.oid=5219984&ac.admitted=1424948823425.876444892.199480143#manuals) for more detail.

Comment: This is really helpful info. Have saved for future use. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> dmidecode -t 17

Linux

> dmidecode|less

for esxi 4.x

> smbiosDump

for esxi 5.x

also see this for vmware

http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1003587

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're running VMware ESXi/vSphere, you can run console commands to get more detailed information on the hardware components. Specifically, you should be able to get the part number, and look that up online.

http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1003587

Note from point 2 in particular, that dmidecode is not available on all versions, in which case you can use smbiosDump which will provide the same information.

So to summarize:
"dmidecode | less" or "smbiosDump | less", look for the part number of your memory modules and look them up online to find their specifications.